# Problem with update Android SDK API 28 inside Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-9.0-pie

I want to update my Android API SDK 28 from Studio's SDK Manager . Inside the tab "SDK Platforms" I can check every Android API to instal except the first Android API 28. Can anybody explain me why it's happening?

[image: SDK Platform Window]

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? Do you mean that the "Android API 28" checkbox is not responding to input? If you check the "Show Package Details" checkbox (towards the lower right corner of that dialog), do you see details for API 28, and if so, can you check checkboxes for the individual pieces of the API 28 SDK?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try by checking the "Show Package Details" checkbox which is to the bottom-right side of the screenshot that you have provided. You will be able to see individual packages, see if you are able to download them.